# Java FX program executing problems in Netbeans 8.0.1 vs native Java execution

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I have `Java FX` program executing in `NetBeans 8.0.1` and it runs fine. But something happened to my computer and now then I run the the jar file directly from windows explorer (.jar file in dist directory in Project) the execution is very different. I.e. loading of text file greater than 2 Mb is endless and often fails completely and application stops working.

Java on computer is:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

do you have and idea what it could be the problem?

The code for opening the file is:

```
  private void chooseFile1(ActionEvent event) {
    File file;
    Files files;
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    //Set extension filter
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("ALL files (*.*)", "*.*");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
    //if (file1Location != "") {
    //    fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(file1Location));
    //}
    //Show open file dialog

    file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder((int) file.length());
    String fileReadLine = "";
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        while ((fileReadLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(fileReadLine).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception x) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
    }
    try {
        file1Location = file.getPath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    labelFile1.setText(file.getName());
    prvi.setText(result.toString());

}
```

Comment: Now I see that NetBeans runs on version JDK 1.7.0.75 version. Uff I have to think something now

Comment: Still did not figure out why there is difference in behaviour. I will reinstall net beans again and try to see what is then happening. I will install NetBeans 8.1. maybe the java will then be 1.8.

Comment: I tired now to rebuild the project with NetBeans 8.1 wtih java 1.8.0.71 but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I can not find any answert to this. 
the only thing is that i used Launch4j program and pack jar with JRE 1.7 so that is run under JRE 1.7.
Now program works normally. I do not know what was the problem.